# Minecraft pocket edition 1.12.0.13 how to lower render distance in options.txt

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My phone works pretty well, but it's stuck at a render distance of 5 chunks. How do I lower that in options.txt to 4 (or lower)?

Here's the options.txt file. It's `gfx_viewdistance`, the view distance is 80, and in-game render distance is 5 chunks which causes me tons of lag  in multiplayer and in worlds. Nvm I don't think there's a way to reduce it since I tried 4 x 16 which gave me the number 64. It just keeps setting it back to 5.

```
mp_username:§6D I C E
game_difficulty_new:1
game_thirdperson:0
gfx_dpadscale:1
mp_server_visible:0
mp_xboxlive_visible:1
mp_nex_visible:1
game_language:
game_skintypefull:c18e65aa-7b21-4637-9b63-8ad63622ef01_CustomSlim
game_lastcustomskinnew:c18e65aa-7b21-4637-9b63-8ad63622ef01_CustomSlim
game_recentskin1:c18e65aa-7b21-4637-9b63-8ad63622ef01_Steve
game_recentskin2:c18e65aa-7b21-4637-9b63-8ad63622ef01_Alex
game_recentskin3:
game_haseverloggedintoxbl:1
game_haschosennottosignintoxbl:1
dvce_filestoragelocation:1
ctrl_islefthanded:0
ctrl_usetouchjoypad:1
ctrl_swapjumpandsneak:1
gfx_viewdistance:80
gfx_particleviewdistance:0
gfx_viewbobbing:1
gfx_fancygraphics:0
gfx_transparentleaves:0
gfx_vr_transparentleaves:1
gfx_smoothlighting:1
gfx_vr_smoothlighting:1
gfx_fancyskies:0
gfx_field_of_view:72.4
gfx_msaa:1
gfx_texel_aa_2:0
gfx_gamma:1
gfx_multithreaded_renderer:1
gfx_vsync:1
dev_file_watcher:1
gfx_max_framerate:0
gfx_fullscreen:0
show_advanced_video_settings:0
gfx_guiscale_offset:0
gfx_splitscreen_guiscale_offset:0
gfx_safe_zone_x:1
gfx_safe_zone_y:1
gfx_ui_profile:1
audio_sound:1
audio_music:1
vr_sensitivity:0.5
vr_gamma:0
vr_particle_view_dist:0.25
vr_stutter_turn:1
vr_stutter_turn_sound:1
vr_hmd_displacement:0
vr_renderdistance:80
vr_autojump:1
vr_head_steering:1
vr_stutter_turn_constant_time:1
vr_stereorendering:1
vr_use_normal_hit:0
vr_use_red_flash:1
vr_rstick_pitch_assist:0
vr_rstick_gazeadjust:0
vr_gaze_pitch_boost:1
vr_hud_drift:1
vr_living_room_cursor_centered:1
vr_linear_jump:1
vr_linear_motion:1
vr_sticky_mining:1
vr_sticky_mining_hand:0
vr_tap_turn:0
vr_tapturn_sensitivity:0.375
vr_wheelturn_sensitivity:50
vr_wheelturning_withLowDeadzone_controller:0
vr_180_turns:0
vr_use_comfort_controls_2:1
vr_show_comfort_select_screen:1
vr_livingroom_hint_time:32000
vr_mirror_texture:1
vr_hand_controls_item:1
vr_hand_controls_hud:1
vr_hand_pointer:1
vr_hands_visible:1
vr_ui_mouse_sensitivity:1
vr_msaa:4
store_has_purchased_coins:0
switch_coin_debug:0
old_game_version_major:1
old_game_version_minor:12
old_game_version_patch:0
old_game_version_revision:13
old_game_version_beta:0
realms_show_friend_invites_only:0
number_of_owned_realms:0
number_of_friends_realms:0
realms_view_upsell_screen_count:3
shown_ratings_prompt:0
save_and_quit_count:0
show_worlds_trial_button:1
allow_cellular_data:0
auto_update_mode:1
auto_update_enabled:1
websocket_encryption:0
text_to_speech_discovered:1
chat_text_to_speech:0
ui_text_to_speech:0
ctrl_sensitivity2_mouse:0.6
ctrl_sensitivity2_touch:0.72
ctrl_sensitivity2_gamepad:0.6
ctrl_sensitivity2_motioncontroller:0.6
ctrl_smoothrotationspeed:0.1
ctrl_invertmouse_mouse:0
ctrl_invertmouse_touch:0
ctrl_invertmouse_gamepad:0
ctrl_invertmouse_motioncontroller:0
ctrl_autojump_mouse:1
ctrl_autojump_touch:0
ctrl_autojump_gamepad:1
ctrl_autojump_motioncontroller:1
ctrl_fullkeyboardgameplay:0
feedback_vibration_mouse:1
feedback_vibration_touch:0
feedback_vibration_gamepad:1
feedback_vibration_motioncontroller:1
gfx_toggleclouds:1
ctrl_togglecrouch_mouse:0
ctrl_togglecrouch_touch:1
ctrl_togglecrouch_gamepad:0
ctrl_togglecrouch_motioncontroller:0
last_xuid:2535460472291097
gfx_hidepaperdoll:1
hide_keyboard_tooltips:1
hide_keyboard_tooltips_overridden:0
gfx_tooltips:0
gfx_classic_box_selection:0
gfx_vr_classic_box_selection:0
gfx_splitscreen:0
gfx_hidehud:0
gfx_hidehand:0
vr_hide_hud:0
vr_hide_hand:0
gfx_ingame_player_names:1
gfx_splitscreen_ingame_player_names:1
gfx_interface_opacity:1
gfx_splitscreen_interface_opacity:1
game_ackautosave:0
gfx_showautosaveicon:0
gfx_has_set_safe_zone:0
gfx_field_of_view_toggle:1
gfx_gamepad_cursor:0
hdr_brightness:1
has_set_hdr_brightness:0
ctrl_hotbarOnlyTouch:0
gfx_gamepad_cursor_sensitivity:1
game_hasshownpatchnotice:0
game_shownplatformnetworkconnect:0
screen_animations:1
ctrl_swap_gamepad_ab_buttons:0
ctrl_swap_gamepad_xy_buttons:0
gfx_bubble_particles:0
game_shownplatformpremiumupsell:0
chat_color_code:§f
chat_font_size:12
chat_line_spacing:1
chat_mentions_color_code:§e
chat_typeface:1
content_log_file:0
content_log_gui:0
gameplay_tips_enabled:0
gameplay_tips_should_be_shown:1
iap_owning_account:
last_minecraft_id:3B455326DC7EDDC2
control_tips_should_be_shown:1
inventory_tips_should_be_shown:1
tree_tips_should_be_shown:1
open_inventory_tips_should_be_shown:1
gamepadMappingVersion:1
```

Answer (score 1):

The unit for that option is *blocks*. So if you want to change the distance in chunks you can do so by multiplying your desired value by 16 (a chunk is a  square of 16x16 blocks) and put the result in.

- 3 chunks = 3 * 16 = 48
- 4 chunks = 4 * 16 = 64
- 5 chunks = 5 * 16 = 80
- ...and so on

Comment: Tried that I got 64 put it in and the game litterly resets it back to 80 as default

Comment: have you closed our app completely (removed from background as well)?

Comment: Do you mean mcpe yes I closed that when I edited the options.text file

Comment: It just won't work it let's me add more render distance but won't lower it

Comment: Could be a bug or a newly hardcoded limit I don't know of.. it *should* go down to 4.

Comment: Sadly three chunks still didnt work